# releasing language versions for iPhone apps

Tags: iphone

I have an iPhone app ready to release in English, and am adding different languages. Is it ok to release the English version first, and then add the language translations, or should they all be done at once?

Answer (score 0):

Its perfectly legal to add localizations later in future updates.  But if you want to delay release to add them is really more of a marketing question as to how you believe it will relate to sales/perception of the product.

Answer (score 0):

Time-to-market is important, so I would release the English version first, unless adding more languages is a pain. marketing a new app is tough, but you also want early feedback from the users - what features can they not live with, and what bugs can they not stand? Adding more languages should be straight-forward and documented. Grabbing a market share is a tricky process.